# How to remove one entry from a REG_MULTI_SZ key without Deleting other entries under the same Multi-String

Tags: c#, sql

I am currently writing an App to replace the Manual uninstall process my company has in place for removing our SQL instance.

I need to be able to Remove "ACT7" from the "InstalledInstances" Multi-String in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server, without removing other SQL instance names.

I have found a few articles online that detail how to replace what the Multi-string has in it, however, they overwrite the whole thing and so would get rid of other instance names.

I need to be able to either, just remove "ACT7" from the list, or Copy all entries apart from "ACT7" and create a replacement key with just those values.

This is the first App I have written, and this is the last key I need to change. Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `REG_MULTI_SZ` value is logically a single value; the only way to remove parts of it is to replace it in its entirety.

```
const string instanceKey = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server";
const string instanceName = "ACT7";

List<string> instances = 
    (
        (string[]) Registry.GetValue(instanceKey, "InstalledInstances", new string[] {})
    ).ToList();

if (instances.Remove(instanceName)) {
    Registry.SetValue(instanceKey, "InstalledInstances", instances.ToArray());
}
```

Note that this should not be used as a general way to remove SQL Server instances. Having a "manual uninstall process" for SQL Server, as opposed to SQL Server's own setup (with [`/ACTION=UNINSTALL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt)), is asking for trouble down the road if the manual process fails to remove absolutely everything required.

Comment: Perfect, that should do it thank you. This is just to be used in the situation of SQL instance would not remove through normal uninstall process. Thank you very much for the help